# Parsing JSON to List of Objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I got a json-object that includes two objects of **different classes** in the following form

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"...}{"f1":"v1","f2":"v2"...}
```

In order to retrieve both of the initial objects, I am trying to parse this json to some sort of container and then cast each one.

```
public void update(String JSONmap) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    System.out.println(JSONmap);
    List<Object> list = mapper.readValue(JSONmap, new TypeReference<List<Object>>(){});
    System.out.println("Got list");
    ....
```

the JSONmap is printed out like above, the second line executes without and output but the third line (sysout("Got list")) and the rest of the method never executes.

Should my json-file be formatted in a different way in order to map it to the list or is there any better solution for this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hey, can you post the code for your mapper? I guess you ran into an endless loop there or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an individual JSON object because it contains multiple objects (as you say it's JSON-like)

```
{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"...}{"f1":"v1","f2":"v2"...}
```

This is two objects.  I think if you want to parse it using a standard JSON parser you'll want to use an object structure like

```
{
    'object1':     {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2"...},
    'object2':     {"f1":"v1","f2":"v2"...}
}
```